# Remove cookie if you change navigation in web

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I'm using the Jquery cookie plugin for easy cookie managment
However I have a question,

I have a webshop and I want to empty the web-cart whenever they leave the cart system and go to the home page again, I know it's possible with including

```
$.removeCookie('cookie_cart', { path: '/' });
```

on every page, but maybe there is an easier way to do it?

Cause right now thats the only way I can think  of

Comment: Well actually the cart is exactly something you might want to keep alive for certain amount of time ... it makes a real difference on sales for example, not mentionning obvious improvement in user experience

Comment: @Bartdude I know, but I have different "packs" which contain a lot of items, but if someone chose a pack and decides to change what he wants,  he'll leave back to the home page again. Here I want to remove all set cookies.

Comment: If you wanted to remove the cookie ONLY when they went to the homepage, add the remove cookie function on the homepage based on a referrer check, such as if the use came from within the website.